# I have just implemented css3 pie and am having issues with png's

Tags: html, css, png, css3pie

I have just included css3 pie to show shadows and gradients which seems to work great however as a result of using this my png's now do not display they just show a red 'x' in the place of the image see the link below:

http://www.floodgateone.com/lavender-blue/weddings.html

has anyone ever come across this issue before or could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm not seeing this and when you fix the problem nobody will have any chance of seeing it. Can you include a screenshot instead please?

Comment: Dito. No "red 'x'" in Chrome/Linux.

Comment: Could you also add the browser you're using, IE7 and 8 work fine.
You should look at IE9 though, it's not working all right.

Comment: ah sorry its only in IE7

Comment: The *.png looks fine to me in IE7, IE8 and IE9. However in IE9 you have not set a background for the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the    `background:#666;` on photo-one. See if that makes a difference.

You can also try to do this

```
#photo-one img { background: none }
```

Kind of hard to test since i use firebug for testing but the problem is not in firefox.
Besides that you got more issues. You cannot see the nav in IE9